# Cancellation Token source and nested tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have a doubt with cancellation token source which I am using as shown in the below code:

```
    void Process()
    {
        //for the sake of simplicity I am taking 1, in original implementation it is more than 1
        var cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        Task[] tArray = new Task[1];
        tArray[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            //do some work here
            MainTaskRoutine();
        }, cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do error handling here
        }
    }

    void MainTaskRoutine()
    {
        //for the sake of simplicity I am taking 1, in original implementation it is more than 1
        //this method shows that a nested task is created 
        var cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        Task[] tArray = new Task[1];
        tArray[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            //do some work here

        }, cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         //do error handling here
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit:** further elaboration

**End objective is:** when a user cancels the operation, all the immediate pending tasks(either children or grand children) should cancel.

**Scenario:**
As per above code: 
1. I first check whether user has asked for cancellation 
2. If user has not asked for cancellation then only continue with the task (Please see Process method). 
sample code shows only one task here but actually there can be three or more

Lets say that CPU started processing Task1 while other tasks are still in the Task queue waiting for some CPU to come and execute them. 
User requests cancellation: Task 2,3 in Process method are immediately cancelled, but Task 1 will continue to work since it is already undergoing processing.

In Task 1 it calls method MainTaskRoutine, which in turn creates more tasks.

In the function of MainTaskRoutine I have written: cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

**So the question is:** is it correct way of using CancellationTokenSource as it is dependent on Task.WaitAll()?

Answer (score 4):

**[EDITED]** As you use an array in your code, I assume there could be multiple tasks, not just one. I also assume that within each task that you're starting from `Process` you want to do some CPU-bound work first (`//do some work here`), and then run `MainTaskRoutine`.

How you handle task cancellation exceptions is determined by your project design workflow. E.g., you could do it inside `Process` method, or from where you call `Process`. If your only concern is to remove Task objects from the array where you keep track of the pending tasks, this can be done using [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx). The continuation will be executed regardless of the task's completion status (`Cancelled`, `Faulted` or `RanToCompletion`):

```
Task Process(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tArray = new List<Task>();
    var tArrayLock = new Object();

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        //do some work here

        return MainTaskRoutine(cancellationToken);
    }, cancellationToken);

    // add the task to the array,
    // use lock as we may remove tasks from this array on a different thread
    lock (tArrayLock)
        tArray.Add(task);
    task.ContinueWith((antecedentTask) =>
    {
        if (antecedentTask.IsCanceled || antecedentTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            // handle cancellation or exception inside the task
            // ...
        }
        // remove task from the array,
        // could be on a different thread from the Process's thread, use lock
        lock (tArrayLock)
            tArray.Remove(antecedentTask);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    // add more tasks like the above
    // ...

    // Return aggregated task
    Task[] allTasks = null;
    lock (tArrayLock)
        allTasks = tArray.ToArray();
    return Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}
```

Your `MainTaskRoutine` can be structured in **exactly the same** way as `Process`, and have the same method signature (return a `Task`).

Then you may want to perform a blocking wait on the aggregated task returned by `Process`, or handle its completion asynchronously, e.g:

```
// handle the completion asynchronously with a blocking wait
void RunProcessSync()
{
    try
    {
        Process(_cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
        MessageBox.Show("Process complete");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Process cancelled (or faulted): " + e.Message);
    }
}

// handle the completion asynchronously using ContinueWith
Task RunProcessAync()
{
    return Process(_cancellationTokenSource.Token).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        // check task.Status here
        MessageBox.Show("Process complete (or cancelled, or faulted)");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

// handle the completion asynchronously with async/await
async Task RunProcessAync()
{
    try
    {
        await Process(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        MessageBox.Show("Process complete");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Process cancelled (or faulted): " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Task.Run` will unwrap a nested task, so the task returned from `Task.Run` is actually the one returned by `MainTaskRoutine`. Also note `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` which is used to make sure the continuation clean-up code gets executed before `WhenAll` is triggered.

Comment: I believe the code I posted behaves correctly. All created tasks share the same `cancellationToken`. As long as you periodically call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` inside each task, any pending task will be cancelled. `Process` and `MainTaskRoutine` themselves do not perform any CPU-bound tasks, so they will be cancelled as soon as their all of their child tasks have been (`WhenAll`). You may however add `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` at the very beginning of `Process` and `MainTaskRoutine` to make sure they don't event start any child tasks.

Comment: Is it ok If I keep on passing CancellationTokenSource also as a parameter to Task, so in case that task needed to create any child task it may use this parameter?

Comment: Based on your edit: *End objective is: when a user cancels the operation, all the immediate pending tasks(either children or grand children) should cancel.* Not sure I understand what you mean by *immediate*. You want only the tasks created by `Process` (but not by `MainTaskRoutine`) to be cancelled?

Comment: Yes, you can (and should) pass the same `CancellationTokenSource.Token` to as many tasks as you want, provided they all should logically be cancelled as a result of calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` on that `CancellationTokenSource` object.

Comment: There is one main thread in application that will keep on waiting on Task.WaitAll(). By immediate tasks I meant threads/tasks created by this main thread directly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37894/discussion-between-shankbond-and-noseratio)

Comment: Maybe I still misunderstood your question. I'm not sure why you want to cancel only the tasks created by the main thread directly (`Process`) and keep keep going the tasks created on pool threads (`MainTaskRoutine`), but you can: just don't use `cancellationToken` inside `MainTaskRoutine` and its subtasks. This is as far as I can help with this question, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642252.aspx).

The code now looks like this:
*see the usage of CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource in below code*

```
    void Process()
    {
        //for the sake of simplicity I am taking 1, in original implementation it is more than 1
        var cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        Task[] tArray = new Task[1];
        tArray[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            //do some work here
            MainTaskRoutine(cancellationToken);
        }, cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do error handling here
        }
    }

    void MainTaskRoutine(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //for the sake of simplicity I am taking 1, in original implementation it is more than 1
        //this method shows that a nested task is created 

        using (var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            var cancelToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            Task[] tArray = new Task[1];
            tArray[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                //do some work here

            }, cancelToken);

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tArray);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //do error handling here
            } 
        }
    }
```

Note: I haven't used it, but I will let You know once it is done :)

Comment: Why would you need a new linked cancellation cancellation source? I don't see you calling `Cancel()` on it, anyway. IMO, it makes sense to use at least two tokens with `CreateLinkedTokenSource`.

Comment: @Noseratio as per my question, it is the user that will cancel the immediate tasks, those tasks will trigger these "MainTaskRoutine" tasks. All in all, it will create a ripple effect for all pending tasks. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is the order of cancellation is not important, the single original cancellation token is enough to cancel all tasks.